# Using androidx.navigation.ui and the backstack

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I have made an app which uses the standard `DrawerLayout` template, however i've noticed that the backstack doesn't behave quite like how i was expecting it to.

The layout is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_layout"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The MainActivity.kt is;

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

private var mTablet = false
private lateinit var navController: NavController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

     val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout? = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    if (drawerLayout == null) {
        mTablet = true
    }

    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    val navSet = setOf(
        R.id.nav_journal, R.id.nav_reports, R.id.nav_calendar,
        R.id.nav_templates, R.id.nav_copyright, R.id.nav_instructions,
        R.id.nav_settings, R.id.nav_social, R.id.nav_support
    )

    if (mTablet == false) {
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navSet, drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    } else {
        //TODO setup action bar with Nav Controller
        //appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navSet, toolbar)
        //val navigationView: ViewGroup = findViewById(R.id.navigation_fragment)
    }

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_settings)
        }
        R.id.action_support -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_support)
        }
        R.id.action_social -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_social)
        }
        R.id.action_instructions -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_instructions)
        }
        R.id.action_copyright -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_copyright)
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
}
```

The navigation xml has no hierarchy to it, it is just a collection of fragments which i will exand upon later.

When you use the drawer to navigate the backstack seems to be emptied when you select a new one. for example, if you select Templates then Calendar and press the devices back button it will automatically take you to the Journal (which is set to be the home screen in the navigation), however if you select Social, Support then Settings from the options menu and press the back button on the device Android sucsessfully goes back to Support then Social and then back to Journal before closing the app.

Why does the drawer not behave in the same way?

there seems to be very little information on developer.android.com about androidx.navigation.ui and doesn't have very many methods or functional overrides except for a very specific setup, am i missing a xml attribute?

I get the feeling that if I were to create a proper navigation structure within `mobile_naivgation.xml` it would work but only in the order defined. Rather than the reverse path that the user used.

I am writing my app in Kotlin with Android Studio.

EDIT: my app level build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "appid"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha05'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: could you post you app level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski i have updated the original post to include the `build.gradle` file